# Prevent Child Tags Width Without changing Child Tag CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to restrict child tags width without changing css of child tags

https://jsfiddle.net/iqabb/0vt3qx9m/6/
image is overlapping from parent div (Green). I need to restrict image from overlapping parent div without changing css of image tag.

Please give a solution with **Only** playing with parent div css ,
so that image remian inside parent div

```
.block-content{
  width:400px;
  height:100%;
  background:green;
  position: relative;

}
```

Comment: add overflow hidden to the parent?

Comment: Thanks , but it is cropping image, is there any solution that image  resized?

Comment: Why are you using base64 for a fullsize jpg?

Comment: not without adding css to the image - not much you can do if you  don't want to do anything to the image itself

Comment: @Pete I have used overflow: auto and it worked as it can be scrolled so it would not effect UI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resloved using code below

```
.block-content{
      width:400px;
      height:100%;
      background:green;
      overflow: auto;
    }
```

Image can be scrolled so it would not effect UI